# Regex for multi-line string?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following input:

```
str = """

    Q: What is a good way of achieving this?

    A: I am not sure. Try the following:

    1. Take this first step. Execute everything.

    2. Then, do the second step

    3. And finally, do the last one



    Q: What is another way of achieving this?

    A: I am not sure. Try the following alternatives:

    1. Take this first step from before. Execute everything.

    2. Then, don't do the second step

    3. Do the last one and then execute the above step

"""
```

I want to capture the QA pairs in the input but I am not able to get a good regex to do this. I managed the following:

```
(?ms)^[\s#\-\*]*(?:Q)\s*:\s*(\S.*?\?)[\s#\-\*]+(?:A)\s*:\s*(\S.*)$
```

But, I'm able to capture the input as follows:

```
('Q', 'What is a good way of achieving this?')
('A', "I am not sure. Try the following:\n    1. Take this first step. Execute everything.\n    2. Then, do the second step\n    3. And finally, do the last one\n\n    Q: What is another way of achieving this?\n    A: I am not sure. Try the following alternatives:\n    1. Take this first step from before. Execute everything.\n    2. Then, don't do the second step\n    3. Do the last one and then execute the above step\n")
```

Notice how the second QA pair got captured by the first. If I use a greedy `?` at the end of the answer regex, it does not capture the enumerations. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just reading it line by line?

Comment: @WesAlvaro: So are you suggesting that I read line by line and then handle this using a state-machine based approach rather than a regex?

Comment: Is it a dumb approach to split by `Q:` first(you get two items) and then split by `A:`(you get four: `[[Q, A], [Q, A]]`)?

Comment: What are you doing with the `[\s#\-\*]*` patterns? At first I thought you were trying to match comments, but that doesn't really make sense with `-` and `*`.

Comment: @Legend, yes, I'm suggesting you don't use a regex for this. You should try your hand at creating a co-routine to do it! =D If you want to peek at mine, it's here: http://pythonfiddle.com/simple-coroutine-example-for-qa-parsing

Answer (score 1):

The lazy, but not the best, way to solve it is to explode the string by "Q:" and then just parse the parts with simple /Q:(.+)A:(.+)/msU (in general regexp).

Answer (score 1):

Just using this works fine for me. Only requires trimming a bit of whitespace.

```
(?s)(Q):((?:(?!A:).)*)(A):((?:(?!Q:).)*)
```

Example of use:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = """
...
...     Q: What is a good way of achieving this?
...
...     A: I am not sure. Try the following:
...
...     1. Take this first step. Execute everything.
...
...     2. Then, do the second step
...
...     3. And finally, do the last one  ...      ...   ...
...     Q: What is another way of achieving this?
...
...     A: I am not sure. Try the following alternatives:
...
...     1. Take this first step from before. Execute everything.
...
...     2. Then, don't do the second step
...
...     3. Do the last one and then execute the above step
...
... """
>>> regex = r"(?s)(Q):((?:(?!A:).)*)(A):((?:(?!Q:).)*)"
>>> match = re.findall(regex, str)
>>> map(lambda x: [part.strip().replace('\n', '') for part in x], match)
[['Q', 'What is a good way of achieving this?', 'A', 'I am not sure. Try the following:    1. Take this first step. Execute everything.    2. Then, do the second step    3. And finally, do the last one'], ['Q', 'What is another way of achieving this?', 'A', "I am not sure. Try the following alternatives:    1. Take this first step from before. Execute everything.    2. Then, don't do the second step    3. Do the last one and then execute the above step"]]
```

Even added a little thingie to help you clean the whitespaces at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that smart to write huge regex(yet), so here is my non-regex solution -

```
>>> str = """

    Q: What is a good way of achieving this?

    A: I am not sure. Try the following:

    1. Take this first step. Execute everything.

    2. Then, do the second step

    3. And finally, do the last one



    Q: What is another way of achieving this?

    A: I am not sure. Try the following alternatives:

    1. Take this first step from before. Execute everything.

    2. Then, don't do the second step

    3. Do the last one and then execute the above step

"""
>>> qas = str.strip().split('Q:')
>>> clean_qas = map(lambda x: x.strip().split('A:'), filter(None, qas))
>>> print clean_qas
[['What is a good way of achieving this?\n\n    ', ' I am not sure. Try the following:\n\n    1. Take this first step. Execute everything.\n\n    2. Then, d
o the second step\n\n    3. And finally, do the last one'], ['What is another way of achieving this?\n\n    ', " I am not sure. Try the following alternativ
es:\n\n    1. Take this first step from before. Execute everything.\n\n    2. Then, don't do the second step\n\n    3. Do the last one and then execute the
above step"]]
```

You should clean the whitespaces though. Or you could do what Puciek said.

Just for fun -

```
>>> clean_qas = map(lambda x: map(lambda s: s.strip(), x.strip().split('A:')), filter(None, qas))
>>> print clean_qas
[['What is a good way of achieving this?', 'I am not sure. Try the following:\n\n    1. Take this first step. Execute everything.\n\n    2. Then, do the sec
ond step\n\n    3. And finally, do the last one'], ['What is another way of achieving this?', "I am not sure. Try the following alternatives:\n\n    1. Take
 this first step from before. Execute everything.\n\n    2. Then, don't do the second step\n\n    3. Do the last one and then execute the above step"]]
```

Looks ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying your original solution:

```
(?ms)^[\s#\-\*]*(?:Q)\s*:\s+(\S[^\n\r]*\?)[\s#\-\*]+(?:A)\s*:\s+(\S.*?)\s*(?=$|Q\s*:\s+)
```

- Questions and answers must have at least one space after the `:`.
- Instead of matching questions non-greedily (which won't allow for having multiple `?`'s in one question), don't allow newlines in questions.
- Instead of matching to end of string, non-greedily match until **either** the match is followed by the end of the string **or** it's followed by another question.

Use `re.findall` to get all question/answer matches.