# Regex - Match any character across mutliple lines

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I had an HTML string that looks like:

```
<img src="blah blah blah"><p> blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah</p>
```

How can i read the `blah blah...` using regex? 
I tried (.+?) but its not working, and searched google but didnt found a solution for **Python**.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364589/regex-for-multi-line-string  ?

Comment: What exactly you want to read? The data inside the P tag or exactly multiples "blah[space]"s ?

Comment: @dvm The data inside <p>

Comment: @Taryn its not working. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usual disclaimers about using regex to parse html, this will work:

```
import re
match = re.search("<img[^>]*><p>([^<]*)</p>", subject)
if match:
    blahblah = match.group(1)
    print blahblah
```

**Explanation**

- `<img` matches literal chars
- `[^>]*` matches any chars that are not `>`
- `><p>` matches literal chars
- `([^<]*)` captures any chars that are not `<` to Group 1 (this is what we want)
- `</p>` matches literal chars
- `match.group(1)` contains our string

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I know that using regex to parse HTML is painful, but i dont like Python's HTML parsers

Answer (score 0):

Give you one example for Java:

```
public static void testRegExp() {
    try {
        String input = "<img src=\"blah blah blah\"><p> blah blah" +
    "\n blah blah blah blah blah blah" +
    "\nblah blah blah</p>";
        Pattern pMod = Pattern.compile("(blah\\s+)+");
        Matcher mMod = pMod.matcher(input);
        int beg = 0;
        while (mMod.find()) {
            System.out.println("--------------");
            System.out.println(mMod.group(0));
        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### The output is :

### blah blah

blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah

For Python, I guess the regeular expression is similar.
Good luck & have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code also which uses `(?s)` DOTALL modifier,

```
>>> s = """<img src="blah blah blah"><p> blah blah
... blah blah blah blah blah blah
... blah blah blah</p>"""
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'(?s)(?<=<p>).*?(?=<\/p>)', s).group(0)
>>> print m
 blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```